# why are my PlanningVariables not set prior to calculateScore invoked?

Tags: optaplanner

Just starting off with Optaplanner 7.36.0. A simple project to start. Have 1 @PlanningEntity collection in my Solution class. Each @PlanningEntity instance has 2 @PlanningVariable instance members, both specifying via valueRangeProviderRefs= the 2 List<Team> @ProblemFactCollectionProperty properties in my Solution class. So, I'm expecting the solver.solve() to invoke the getters to set the PlanningVariable properties in the PlanningEntity instances. but when the calculateScore() method is invoked, the provided Solution instance has the collection of PlanningEntity instances, all with unset PlanningVariable properties. And my breakpoint on the PlanningVariable setter is never triggered - which is consistent with the PlanningEntity instances having their PlanningVariables unset but why?

Using the Conferencescheduling in the optaplanner-examples to guide me but I'm obviously missing some detail, what's not obvious to me is which might be responsible for unassigned PlanningVariables. I'm NOT using the nullable = true setting in my @PlanningVariable annotation uses. But can something else be causing similar behaviors?

The solution instance I handoff to the solver.solve() method has uninitialized PlanningVariables as mentioned above, as well as an uninitialized @PlanningScore property in my @PlanningSolution class. Nor am I providing/overriding the cloneSolution method in my Solution class as I don't have any references back to the Solution from the PlanningEntity instances. It my understanding having unitialized PlanningVariables is the expected state, perhaps I'm missing/confused important aspects?

Here is the solverConfig.xml I'm using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">
  <environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode><!-- To slowly prove there are no bugs in this code -->
  <!-- Domain model configuration -->
  <solutionClass>org.shespelt.uslnj.domain.Season</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>org.shespelt.uslnj.domain.Fixture</entityClass>
  <!-- Score configuration -->
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <easyScoreCalculatorClass>org.shespelt.uslnj.score.SeasonEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>
  <!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
  <termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>300</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
  <!-- Tabu Search performs much better than Late Acceptance (default algo) on this use case -->
  <constructionHeuristic/>

  <exhaustiveSearch>
    <exhaustiveSearchType>BRUTE_FORCE</exhaustiveSearchType>
  </exhaustiveSearch>
</solver>
```

The @PlanningEntity class

```java
package org.shespelt.uslnj.domain;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.entity.PlanningEntity;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable;

/**
 * see section 18.4.1 regarding making a PlanningEntity immovable (ie. a match must be defined by the current
 * home & away teams for the given PlanningEntity (Fixture.class). Might be useful? along with the PlanningPin
 */

@PlanningEntity
public class Fixture extends AbstractPersistable {

    private Integer matchDay = null;

    @PlanningVariable( valueRangeProviderRefs = {"homeTeamRange"})
    private Team homeTeam=null;

    @PlanningVariable( valueRangeProviderRefs = {"awayTeamRange"})
    private Team awayTeam=null;

    public Fixture( long id, int matchDay, Team homeTeam, Team awayTeam ) {
        super.setId(id);
        this.matchDay = matchDay;
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
        System.out.println("Fixture() -> just created via non-empty CTOR. ID: " + this.getId().toString());
    }
    // the no-arg Ctor only needed by Optaplanner framework - when cloning so it ought to handle, through
    // reflection, the setting of all of the properties.
    public Fixture() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Fixture() - no-arg CTOR invoked. ID: " +
                ( this.getId() != null ? this.getId().toString():"NULL") );
    }

    //@PlanningVariable( valueRangeProviderRefs = { "matchDayRange"})
    public Integer getMatchDay() {
        return matchDay;
    }

    public void setMatchDay(Integer theMatchDay) {
        this.matchDay = theMatchDay;
    }


    public Team getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public void setHomeTeam(Team homeTeam) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    }


    public Team getAwayTeam() {
        return awayTeam;
    }

    public void setAwayTeam(Team awayTeam) {
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fixture: " + this.getId() + ", matchDay: " + this.getMatchDay() +
                ", homeTeam: " + this.getHomeTeam() + ", awayTeam: " + this.getAwayTeam();
    }
}
```

Here is my main() - simple stuff to start with...

```java
// build the solver
SolverFactory<Season> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(
               "org/shespelt/uslnj/seasonSolverConfig.xml");
Solver<Season> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
// instantiate the uninitialized Season - with our Fixtures, Teams, Divisions,
Season unsolvedSeason = loadData();

// solve it
Season scheduledSeason = solver.solve( unsolvedSeason );
scheduledSeason.showSchedule();
```

updated observation:  the final solution has an poor score (hard: -2000, soft:-409,600) but that's better than the worse possible of (hard:-214749364, soft:-214748364)
and I'm getting a number of caculateScore() calls returning this worse case (all the Fixture PlanningEntity's PlanningVariables are unset (the specific team instances). Total of 337 scores being calculated, 261 of those are worst-case - both PlanningVariables of the PlanningEntity are unset when calculateScore() called.

The best case is still bad in that only 1 team is set as the homeTeam, also set as the awayTeam - same pairing for all Fixtures in the Season. Hence the -2000 score - logic returns -1000 hard for a calculateScore() case where the 2 teams are the same.

Might I be on the 'right' track by thinking I've got to implement some kind of MoveSelector ? as I'm rather 'concerned' that only 1 team from each of the homeTeamList, awayTeamList List instances are being considered for each solution. Because I'm seeing 1 team being used for all the Fixture instances (all of the PlanningEntity instances) for both declared PlanningEntity collections. each PlanningVariable has a provided valueRangeProviderRefs which is a different List in my PlanningSolution. Is that enough? it only runs for 1 second.

Perhaps my problem is that I'm not modeling my domain correctly. Comparing to how the example Traveling Tournament is modeled but the two have to be different. In my domain, the dates for the entire set of fixtures is set (planning facts) but what I need to solve for is what fixture matchups meet all the constraints - both hard & soft - in a 'best' case solution, for all of the fixtures in a 'Season' (the Planning Solution made up of a list of PlanningEntity (Fixture class instances).
Thanks,

Comment: Can you share your `solverConfig.xml` and your `@PlanningEntity` class source?

Comment: Hi yurloc, Yes - I've edited the post; added the config.xml file & @PlanningEntity class at the end of the post. Appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: I can't see anything suspicious about the config and domain model. Maybe the issue is that you examine the unsolved problem - the `@PlanningSolution` instance that you pass to `solver.solve()` method. But note that the solver will never modify the instance you gave it to solve. It will clone it when it starts solving and it will give you another clone representing the best solution found when it stops solving. You have to do something like `Season solvedSeason = solver.solve(unsolvedSeason);` and then examine `solvedSeason` instance. Please confirm you follow this approach.

Comment: Hi yurloc,
I've added the code from my main() - showing the pattern you asked about. Yes, it's following the approach you described. Thanks again.

Comment: I have to confess, my coding experience using the reflection API is limited & dated 
 (2004?).
Have I made an error in assuming that with the PlanningVariable annotation on the 2 Team properties in my PlanningEntity, that the 2 getHomeTeam(), getAwayTeam() methods will still be invoked OR is the access via reflection done solely based on the determined type of each valueRangeProvider's List? That perhaps, for some yet unknown reason, the setting of the PlanningVariables isn't even attempted?

Comment: Strange. The `main()` snippet looks good. At which point do you examine the solution instance and find uninitialized planning variables? If you set break point on `calculateScore()` it's possible that score calculation is done on an uninitialized solution for the first time, which is OK. If you get NPEs in your easy score calculator because of uninitialized planning variables, you should do null checks because, as I said, score calculation can happen on an uninitialized solution.

Comment: It is strange, I'm looking at the returned solution, and yes - I'm checking for uninitialized planning variables in the calculateScore method, for the very reason you give.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source code of your planning solution? Better yet, put a simplified runnable version somewhere on Github, so that we can look into it efficiently,@Steve?

Comment: Hi Lukas, Yes - let me set that up.  
updated observation:  the final solution has an poor score (hard: -2000, soft:-409,600) but that's better than the worse possible of (hard:-214749364, soft:-214748364)
and I'm getting a number of caculateScore() calls returning this worse case (all the Fixture PlanningEntity's PlanningVariables are unset (the specific team instances).

Comment: Once I have the code up on Github, I'll post a comment to that effect.

Comment: my code is now available at https://github.com/shespelt/FixtureScheduler. Please let me know if there anything I can add, update, explain that might help you to help me :-)
many thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Possible answer:  this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66063885/equal-distribution-of-schedules has an answer showing the use of a <selectionOrder>RANDOM</selectionOrder> element in a changeMoveSelector for localSearch. Now I'm getting the full list of ValueRangeProvider utilized (before I was getting only 1 Team utilized in possible solutions). Need to add a few more criteria into my calculateScore().

But the great news is the solver is running to a much better score (0 hard :-). Significant progress. And I deserve 0 credit... but Stackoverflow poster does